# executing a sql query at a particular time

Tags: mysql, windows, cron

I need to execute a SQL query two hours after I insert a row in a particular table.

I can create a trigger to execute that query, but the problem is that i have to run it after two hours. I know MySQL 5.1.6 and later support `events`, but I have a `5.1.4` version. Upgrading is a solution, but can I do this without using events?

I am using Windows -- is there something like `cron` on Linux that I can use to schedule the job?

Comment: You might be able to cook up something with the windows task sheduler, but even better is to just rethink the software you're writing. I can't think of a sane reason that this needs to be done that can't be solved better/otherwise.

Comment: Windows does supply an `at` command _and_ a [more generic scheduling system](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events (also called 'Jobs' on other DBMSs) are what you are looking for, but if you're on Windows, you could also write a script performing your actions. You can connect to MySQL from PHP or others kinds of scripts and execute any queries you want or run a stored procedure. This scripts can then be scheduled using the Scheduled Tasks feature of Windows.

Comment: can i do it from the database. is there something like `execute query at` or something in triggers in mysql?

Comment: Not in versions before 5.1.6, afaik. :-/

Comment: can u give an example of a script which i can use to schedule query execution?